# Wizard control for UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm looking for a sample wizard control for UWP. I am looking for a control that uses forward and backward buttons to transition from one panel to the next.

I have tried to implement my own by animating the width of panels in a horizontally oriented StackPanel, but it doesn't work as expected (the width is not animated and reverts back).

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="GoToNextAnimation" Storyboard.TargetName="LeftPanel">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="100" To="0" AutoReverse="False"  Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100" Tapped="StackPanel_Tapped" Background="Red" Height="50">
    <Button x:Name="LeftPanel" Background="Yellow" Width="100" Height="50" />
    <Button x:Name="RightPanel" Background="Green" Width="100" Height="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

with the event handler beginning the animation:

```
bool isLeft = true;
private void StackPanel_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isLeft)
    {
        GoToNextAnimation.Begin();
    }
    else
    {
        LeftPanel.Width = 100;
    }

    isLeft = !isLeft;
}
```

When I tep the control it briefly (much quicker than the animation is intended to run for) changes to the red color (background of StackPanel) before reverting back to yellow (*never showing the green for the RightPanel).

Comment: The closest UWP control for what you're trying to achieve is FlipView. But it's likely not exactly what you're looking for. Have you tried re-templating a FlipView?

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: Try this manual https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages